# Google Analytics goal tracking with url parameter

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to setup conversion tracking on a site, where a form can be filled on different pages. The only thing that the confirmation url after filling a form is ?surveySucces, so pages where a form is filled could be:

domain.com/landingpage?surveySuccess
or
domain.com/landingpage/subpage?surverySuccess

I just want to setup up one goal, so I can track all the forms that are filled. I've tried with RegEx, but with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try these goal settings:

- **Goal setup**: Custom
- **Type**: Destination
- **Match type**: Regular expression
- **Value**: \?surveySuccess
- **Case sensitive**: unchecked